# "bootstrap" circular images list with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want like this https://s24.postimg.org/czsfzbujp/Untitled.jpg

code link is https://jsfiddle.net/sheraz_bootstrap_dev/o4xuwosk/
for first un-ordered-list item i want the the div with class timeline-panel to left side of the circle image.
the next list item timeline-panel should be on right side but both circle images remain vertically centered.

here is the code

```css
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline>li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.timeline-panel {
  width: 41%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
.img-circle {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 7px solid #F1F1F1;
}
```

```html
<section id="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>2009-2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>March 2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>lorem ipsum Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: is it what you need?: https://jsfiddle.net/6uq3ffon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Display:flex`, `flex-flow` , `calc()`, `position` can help, a pseudo  too to draw that line.

```css
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  
  
  .timeline-panel {
    width: calc(50% - 90px);/* updated */
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .img-circle {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 7px solid #F1F1F1;
  }

/* added */

.timeline>li {/* modified */
    display: flex;
    padding:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .timeline>li .timeline-image {
    order:2;
    position:relative;
  }
  .timeline>li.timeline-inverted{
    flex-flow:row-reverse
  }
  .timeline> li + li {
    margin-top:50px;
  }
  .timeline:before {    
    content:'';
    background:gray;
    width:1px;top:50px;
    bottom:50px;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>2009-2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>March 2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Demo with 2 `li` https://jsfiddle.net/o4xuwosk/7/ or more  https://jsfiddle.net/o4xuwosk/8/

---

with `calc()` , you can also set some horizontal padding on `ul` to avoid the timeline being too wide. https://jsfiddle.net/o4xuwosk/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here try that, no CSS required, everything done with bootstrap
(You would need to enlarge the preview window cause u chose LG, then it will automatically adjust for your needs.)

```
[Fiddle][1]


https://jsfiddle.net/pfrptb9d/
```

Comment: yes but there is css involved a lil bit see the first link for image i given at top....